# Color dataframe by rows

Tags: r

Can anyone help me with coloring a dataframe? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You are going to need to be more precise. Do you want to plot the data frame once it's coloured? Should `.` remain white/blank? Looks like in your example data everything is going to be red, right?

Comment: Hello @JuliusVainora , No I don't want to plot it. I want to save it as an image. The entire row 2 will be in blue. column 38- row 4 - D; column 43 -row 3 -I etc will be blue.(They have same alphabet like row 2)

Comment: I forgot to mention, row1 should not be compared. It should be left as it is.

Comment: Dots should remain black. Thank you! (I tried using htmltable and kable but I couldn't group the data properly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach with ggplot and dplyr.

First I convert the given data into a long format, one letter per table row, with numeric column and row coordinates.

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
ltrs_tidy <- alpha_ltrs %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "row") %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  tidyr::gather(col, ltr, -row) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(c("row", "col")), 
            ~str_remove(., "r|c") %>% as.integer)
```

Then I calculate what colors to use by appending a new column showing the row 2 value for that column, and then specify rules in the `case_when` statement.

```
ltrs_tidy2 <- ltrs_tidy %>%
  left_join(ltrs_tidy %>% filter(row == 2) %>% select(col, ltr_row2 = ltr), by = "col") %>%
  mutate(fill_calc = case_when(
    row == 1         ~ "white",
    row == 2         ~ "blue",
    ltr %in% c(".")  ~ "white",
    ltr == ltr_row2  ~ "blue",
    TRUE             ~ "red"
  ))
```

Finally, I plot a shaded `geom_tile` and `geom_text` at each location.

```
ggplot(ltrs_tidy2, aes(col, row, label = ltr, fill = fill_calc)) +
  geom_tile(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_text(size = 2.5, family = "mono") +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 2) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: Hello @JonSpring, Thank you very much. Could you please delete the plot? It is from my research work. Thanks!